Getting NullInjectorError: No provider for function(options) in Angular 17
I'm a beginner in Angular (17 version). I'm getting error:
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_LoginPageComponent])[function(options) { -> function(options) { -> function(options) { -> function(options) { -> function(options) {]:
[1]   NullInjectorError: No provider for function(options) {!
while adding private router: Router to constructor() in login-page.component.ts.
login-page.component.ts
import { CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/layouts/services/auth.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from 'express';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login-page.component.css'
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit{
  form : FormGroup
  aSub: Subscription
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email, Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])
    })
  }
  

  onSubmit() {
    this.form.disable()

    this.aSub = this.auth.login(this.form.value).subscribe({
      next: (result) => {
      },

      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.form.enable()
      }
    })
  }
}

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(), provideHttpClient(withFetch())]
};


auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "../interfaces";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    
    }

    register() {

    }

    login(user: User): Observable<{token: string}> {
        return this.http.post<{token: string}>('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login', user)
    }
}

Help me figure out what the problem is. Thanks!

import RouterModule perhaps?

Router should be importer from @angular/router
Replace
import { Router } from 'express';

with
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

